# Duplicate Posts In Custom Post Type by Taxonomy

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a Custom Post Type called Products (not WooCommerce). The user selects the Categories using an ACF Taxonomy Field. I'm trying to get each Product per selected Category but some of the products are in multiple categories so when I am looping through the rows they are printing multiple times.

```
<?php
$product_categories = get_field( 'product_filter_categories' );
$custom_taxonomy='product_category';  
$custom_terms = $product_categories;

foreach($custom_terms as $custom_term) :
    wp_reset_query();

    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'product',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'tax_query' => array(               
            array(
                'taxonomy' => $custom_taxonomy,
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' => $custom_term->slug,
            ),
        ),
    );  

    $loop = new WP_Query($args);

    if($loop->have_posts()) :
        $product_coming_soon_image = get_field( 'product_coming_soon_image' );

        while($loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post();
            $termsArray = get_the_terms( $post->ID, "product_category" );

            $termsString = "";
            foreach ( $termsArray as $term ) {
                $termsString .= $term->slug.' ';
            } ?>

            <div class="<?php echo $termsString; ?> isotope-item">
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">                            
                    <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) :  ?>
                        <img src="<?php the_post_thumbnail_url('') ?>" class="lazy" alt="<?php the_title() ?>" loading="lazy" width="240" height="240">
                    <?php else : ?>
                        <img src="<?php echo esc_url( $product_coming_soon_image['sizes']['our-products'] ); ?>" alt="<?php echo esc_attr( $product_coming_soon_image['alt'] ); ?>" loading="lazy" width="240" height="240" />
                    <?php endif; ?>
                </a>
                <h3><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
            </div>

            <?php
        endwhile; ?>

    <?php
    endif;
endforeach; ?>
</div>
```

I can't determine where the duplicates are coming from.

Comment: So those are duplicates with the same post ID?

Comment: When you have duplicates, do you have some posts missing? Or so in the end you have more posts than in your DB? Isthe wp_query post_count wrong? You can also test `setup_postdata( $post );` at beginning of while loop, but I thought the_post() was enough.

Comment: Updated question to reflect that some of the products are in multiple categories so when I am looping through the rows they are printing multiple times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to remove the duplicates by creating an empty array just before the first foreach and then checking if the current post ID was in that array while looping. If the the current post id was not in the array, add it to the array and show the product. If the current post id is in the array, skip it.

Updated Code

```
$product_categories = get_field( 'product_filter_categories' );
$custom_taxonomy = 'product_category';
$custom_terms = $product_categories;
$displayed_products = array();

foreach($custom_terms as $custom_term) :
    wp_reset_query();

    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'product',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => $custom_taxonomy,
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' => $custom_term->slug,
            ),
        ),
    );  

    $loop = new WP_Query($args);

    if($loop->have_posts()) :
        $product_coming_soon_image = get_field( 'product_coming_soon_image' );

        while($loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post();
            if(!in_array( $post->ID, $displayed_products )) :
                $termsArray = get_the_terms( $post->ID, "product_category" );

                $termsString = "";
                foreach ( $termsArray as $term ) {
                    $termsString .= $term->slug.' ';
                } ?>

                <div class="<?php echo $termsString; ?> isotope-item">
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                        <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) :  ?>
                            <img src="<?php the_post_thumbnail_url('') ?>" class="lazy" alt="<?php the_title() ?>" loading="lazy" width="240" height="240">
                        <?php else : ?>
                            <img src="<?php echo esc_url( $product_coming_soon_image['sizes']['our-products'] ); ?>" alt="<?php echo esc_attr( $product_coming_soon_image['alt'] ); ?>" loading="lazy" width="240" height="240" />
                        <?php endif; ?>
                    </a>
                    <h3><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
                </div>

                <?php
                array_push( $displayed_products, $post->ID );
            endif;
        endwhile; ?>

    <?php
    endif;
endforeach; ?>
'''
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so what you are doing is :

- getting some terms
- looping on terms
- getting products by the term
- looping on products for display

So indeed, if a product is associated with multiple terms in the loop, they'll appear multiple times this way.

You should remove the first foreach, and query product by multiple terms, then loop on the wp_query results. This way you won't have duplicates:

```
$args = array(
            'post_type' => 'product',
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'tax_query' => array(
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => $custom_taxonomy,
                    'field' => 'slug',
                    'terms' => array_column($custom_term, 'slug'),
                ),
            ),
        );
```

If you really need to loop on your terms, and query product on each loop: you'll need to store all queried post ids in an array from initiated outside the loop. And add to the query "post not in: ids" with this array of ids "already queried".

Comment: $custom term is defined in the foreach loop. If I remove the foreach loop then I don't have the products in each category. Can you list the full code as you see it?

Comment: hum `$custom_terms` is defined outside of the loop. It comes from `$product_categories = get_field( 'product_filter_categories' );` no ?

Comment: Yes, ```$custom_terms``` is the list of Product Categories but the foreach loop gets all the products within those categories. In your code sample, you are using ```$custom_term```. Should that be ```$custom_terms```? Even so, I am only getting a handfull of products rather than the entire list.

Comment: Well, `custom_terms` contains an array of terms, exactly like your example. What you are doing is "loop all categories, and get the product for each category for 2nd loop", what I'm doing is "get all product from all those categories, and loop them" so only 1 loop.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I was able to figure it out and posted my answer below.

Comment: Cool. Note that your solution will make a new DB query on every loop, my first solution could prevent this by doing a single DB query. You can also add `post__not_in => $displayed_products ` to your in-loop query to don't query already queried products

Comment: Nice, thanks for the additional tips!

Comment: Glad it helped, please upvote or accept if it suited you. Happy coding :)

Answer (score -1):

```
$product_categories = get_field( 'product_filter_categories' );
$custom_taxonomy='product_category';  
$custom_terms = $product_categories->term_id;

foreach($custom_terms as $custom_term) :
    

    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'product',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'tax_query' => array(               
            array(
                'taxonomy' => $custom_taxonomy,
                'field' => 'term_id',
                'terms' => array($custom_terms),
                'operator' => 'IN',
            ),
        ),
    );  

    $loop = new WP_Query($args);

    if($loop->have_posts()) :
        $product_coming_soon_image = get_field( 'product_coming_soon_image',get_the_ID());

        while($loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post();
            $termsArray = get_the_terms( get_the_ID(), "product_category" );

            $termsString = "";
            foreach ( $termsArray as $term ) {
                $termsString .= $term->slug.' ';
            } ?>

            <div class="<?php echo $termsString; ?> isotope-item">
                <a href="<?php get_permalink(); ?>">                            
                    <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) :  ?>
                        <img src="<?php the_post_thumbnail_url('') ?>" class="lazy" alt="<?php get_the_title() ?>" loading="lazy" width="240" height="240">
                    <?php else : ?>
                        <img src="<?php echo esc_url( $product_coming_soon_image['sizes']['our-products'] ); ?>" alt="<?php echo esc_attr( $product_coming_soon_image['alt'] ); ?>" loading="lazy" width="240" height="240" />
                    <?php endif; ?>
                </a>
                <h3><a href="<?php echo get_permalink()(); ?>"><?php get_the_title(); ?></a></h3>
            </div>

            <?php
        endwhile; wp_reset_query();?>

    <?php
    endif;
endforeach; ?>
</div>
```